# Confused about nested resources and authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, crud

Let's see if I can explain myself well enough about the doubts I have.

I have a User model that is managed by Devise.  So in my routes I have:

```
devise_for :users
```

In the **User** model, I have an association with the model **Plan**.  The assocation is:

```
User has_many Plans
Plan belongs_to User
```

At this point I also have a resource for the Plan model, so I can fetch all the Plans, show a particular plan and so on.  But I want to go further.

I want to be able to see plans of a particular User and let a particular User to see his own plans and edit them.

So, for example, whenever I go to:

/users/:id/plans

I want to be able to see the plans for that particular :id user. And if the user who is visiting that url is the one that is logged in, I want him to be able to edit those plans.

How can I manage all this behavior? Is there any gem out there that helps with it? Or I need to do conditionals in the views saying if current_user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with routes, you can make your routes like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :plans, only: [:index]
end

resources :plans, except: [:index]
```

I used `resources :plans` inside `resources :users` to have route like this `/users/:user_id/plans`, while the `resources :plans` outside is for the rest of the actions (edit, destroy, ...) that don't require a `user_id`, i.e., a plan is identified by a unique id so you don't need a `user_id` to fetch it from the db for editing or destroying.

Now for the controller, we can make it like this:

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_plan_owner?, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @plans = Plan.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end

  def edit
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def is_plan_owner?
    if current_user != Plan.find(params[:id]).user
      # Scream, shout, call 911 and/or redirect else where
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is no different than using any other nested resource. The call to `devise_for` in the `routes.rb` file does not provide RESTful routing to the user model. Think about it without the nested resource for a minute, with just a standard Devise install. If you were to `rake routes` you would get something similar to the following:

```
  new_user_session GET  /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
      user_session POST /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
     user_password POST /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
 new_user_password GET  /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET  /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
           sign_in GET  /sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
```

This provides nothing for indexing or showing users, so you would still need to add routes for that:

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
```

Now you get:

```
users GET /users(.:format)     users#index
 user GET /users/:id(.:format) users#show
```

Ok, now we're getting somewhere, then it's simply adding the nested resource, all the while Devise pays it no mind.

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :plans
end
```

Which gives you the resourceful routing you desire

```
    user_plans GET /users/:user_id/plans(.:format)          plans#index
              POST /users/:user_id/plans(.:format)          plans#create
 new_user_plan GET /users/:user_id/plans/new(.:format)      plans#new
edit_user_plan GET /users/:user_id/plans/:id/edit(.:format) plans#edit
     user_plan GET /users/:user_id/plans/:id(.:format)      plans#show
               PUT /users/:user_id/plans/:id(.:format)      plans#update
            DELETE /users/:user_id/plans/:id(.:format)      plans#destroy
```

And that's really all there is to it. Devise stays out of your way on this one.