# devise redirect on login error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DocumentsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I 'm trying to redirect to a specific page after sign_in & sign_up. I have two models users & resources. After sign_in I want to show list of documents that belong to the user. 
If there are no documents then it should redirect to users/:id/document#create otherwise users/:id/document#index.

Any suggestions how do i do that?

I get the following error for the redirect path defined in my controller.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DocumentsController#show
>
> Couldn't find Document without an ID

**Application_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
 user_documents_url(user)
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
 root :to => 'home#index'

   devise_for :users

   resources :users do
        resources :documents
   end
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
```

**Routes**

```
root        /                                        home#index
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)                         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)                        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                                        devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /                                        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                                        devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /confirmation/new(.:format)              devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#show
          user_documents POST   /users/:user_id/documents(.:format)      documents#create
      new_user_documents GET    /users/:user_id/documents/new(.:format)  documents#new
     edit_user_documents GET    /users/:user_id/documents/edit(.:format) documents#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/documents(.:format)      documents#show
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/documents(.:format)      documents#update

        /user/:user_id/documents(.:format)       user/documents#index
```

Thanks

Comment: Your routes don't show the documents#index action. Are you sure you posted the correct routes.rb and rake routes output? `resources :documents` should generate a path to the index action.

Comment: updated my route to include documents#index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090894/confused-about-nested-resources-and-authentication-in-rails).Following is my routes.rb

```
   resources :users do
        resources :documents, only: [:index]
   end
   resource :documents, except: [:index]
```

this gives me document#index path as well as document#new path.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself has no problem as I see. But you need to build some "documents" data before this test, either by FactoryGirl or stubs.

Because you really don't have "documents" data for any users, of course Rails gave you to RecordNotFound error.

Comment: i do have documents associated with the user. The error says couldnt find a document because it is trying to show a document and I have not passed a "document id"

Comment: What's your `index` method? Does it return any data?

Answer (score 0):

use this method according to following code

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
     // redirect path
  end
```

i hope this will help

Comment: The solution you are suggesting is incorrect as there is no resource called dashboard

Comment: This piece of code related to my project  you can change it according to your needs. :)